# polynomial approximation in Hardy space $H^\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, fourier-series

$H^\infty$ is the [Hardy space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Hardy_spaces_for_the_unit_disk) of **bounded analytic functions** on the open unit disk $|z| < 1$ with the norm $$\|f\|  = \sup_{ |z| \,< \,1}|f(z)|$$
It has two important subspaces :

- $H^\infty_C$ the (closed) subspace of analytic functions that stay **continuous** on the closed unit disk $|z|\le 1$.
- $H^\infty_K $ the subspace of functions whose Taylor series stay **convergent** on $|z| = 1$

**Question** : Can you show that $H^\infty_C \subseteq H^\infty_K$, or find a counter-example $f \in H^\infty_C, f \not\in H^\infty_K$  ?

---

Attempt :

- $f \in H^\infty_C, f \not\in H^\infty_K$ means its Fourier series diverges, so it can't be [Holder continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Absolute_convergence) on the boundary, and the [Dini's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence) should diverge. That's why I thought to $f(z) = \frac{z}{\log(1-z)}$, but it seems its Taylor coefficients are all of the same sign, so [Abel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem#Remarks) guarantees it converges. Next try  : things like $\frac{1}{\log \log (1-z)}$ or $\frac{1}{\log \log \log \log (1-z)}$ (the branch $\log(1) = 2i\pi$)
- [there is a proof of existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Example:_pointwise_convergence_of_Fourier_series) (but no example) of a $2\pi$-periodic continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at one point (but it doesn't have to be analytic, so it doesn't apply here)
- $f_N(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$ is the truncated Taylor series. With $r \to 1^-$ , and $N \to \infty$ :
  $$\begin{eqnarray}\|f(z)-f_N(rz)\| & \ =\ & \|(f(z)-f(rz))+(f(rz)-f_N(rz))\| \\
  & \le &  \|f(z)-f(rz)\|+\|f(rz)-f_N(rz)\|
  \end{eqnarray}
  $$
  $f \in H^\infty_C$ means it is uniformly continuous on $|z| \le 1$ so that $ \|f(z)-f(rz)\| = o(r)$, and $f(rz)$ is analytic on $1/r > 1$ hence it is approximated uniformly on $|z| \le 1$  by its truncated Taylor series $f_N(rz)$, so that $\|f(rz)-f_N(rz)\| = o_r(N)$ and
  $$\|f(z)-f_N(rz)\| = o(r)+o_r(N)$$
  showing that the polynomials are dense in $H^\infty_C$.
- But doing the same for $\|f(z) - f_N(z)\|$ is more complicated :
  $$\begin{eqnarray}\|f(z)-f_N(z)\| & \ =\ & \|(f(z)-f_N(rz))+(f_N(rz)-f_N(z))\| \\
  & \le &  \|f(z)-f_N(rz)\|+\|f_N(rz)-f_N(z)\| \\
  & = & o(r)+o_r(N) + \mathcal{O}((r-1)N)
  \end{eqnarray}
  $$
  Ideally, if $f \in H^\infty_K$ then we would have $\|f_N(rz)-f_N(z)\|< \alpha \|f(rz)-f(z)\| = o(r)$ so that $\|f(z)-f_N(z)\| = o(r) + o_r(N)$.

  Hence, for showing $f \in H^\infty_K$, one needs a good bound for $\|f_N(rz)-f_N(z)\|$, probably [using that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)
  $$f_N(rz)-f_N(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|s| = R} \frac{f(s)}{s} \left(\frac{1-(rz/s)^{N+1}}{1-rz/s}-\frac{1-(z/s)^{N+1}}{1-z/s}\right)ds$$

Comment: I'm confused. Is $f(z) = 1/(z-1)$ in $H^\infty$ ? it's analytic on the open unit disk but it doesn't have a norm. Also what is $f$ in question 2 ? Easier than what ?

Comment: @mercio $g \in H^\infty$ if it is analytic and bounded on $|z| < 1$. and $f \in H^\infty_C$ has to be also continuous on $|z| \le 1$. A non-trivial example is $f(z) = \frac{z}{\ln(1-z)} \in H^\infty_C$, the question being if its Taylor series converges on $|z| = 1$ or not, i.e. if $\frac{z}{\ln(1-z)} \in H^\infty_K$.

Comment: do you know Cauchy's integral formula ?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: actually, one can show that $z/\log(1-z)$ is in the Wiener algebra, meaning that its Taylor expansion converges absolutely on the closed unit disk, so it's not a good example.

Comment: @mercio I tried to correct the mistakes. What are you thoughts ? tks

Comment: What about $f(z)=(z-1)e^{\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}}$ for $|z|\leq 1$, $z\neq 1$ and 0 at $z=1$? If $|z|\leq 1$, $z\neq 1$, then $Re \dfrac{z+1}{z-1} \leq 0$. Thus $\lim_{z\to 1} f(z)=0$ and  $f\in H_C^\infty$.

Comment: @ChrisApostol it will be similar to $ e^{1/(z-1)}$ : $f(e^{it})$ is $C^\infty$ and its Fourier series converges ($f \in H^\infty_K$)

Comment: What about $z=1$?

Comment: @ChrisApostol $f(z)$ is analytic on $|z| < 1$, and by definition here $f(e^{it}) = \lim_{r \to 1^-} f(r e^{it})$. $\ f \in H_C^\infty$ if the obtained $f(z)$ is continuous on $|z| \le 1$. What I'm saying is that $e^{1/(z-1)}$ is in $H^\infty_C$ and all its derivatives too ($f'(z) \in H^\infty_C$ is enough), hence its Taylor series converges on $|z| = 1$ and $e^{1/(z-1)} \in H^\infty_K$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question** : Can you show that $H^\infty_C \subseteq H^\infty_K$, or find a counter-example $f \in H^\infty_C, f \not\in H^\infty_K$  ?

**Answer** : Neither. The two spaces are certainly different, but one cannot write down a simple example showing this.

The second assertion is not something I'm going to try to prove mathematically. It's true in the same sort of sense that "there is no simple proof of Fermat's  last theorem" is true. A simple example of a function in $H^\infty_C\setminus H^\infty_K$ would in particular be a simple example of a continuous function on the circle with a divergent Fourier series, and there is no such example. At least nobody has ever given such an example; this "shows" that simple constructions as in the OP and the comments "cannot" succeed, because if it were possible someone would have done it by now.

The space $H^\infty_C$ is commmonly known as the "disk algebra", denoted $A$; I will use this notation below.

The existence of $f\in A$ such that the power series for $f$ does not converge on the boundary follows fairly easily from the fact mentioned above, that there exists a function in $C(\Bbb T)$ with a divergent Fourier series. The implication would be utterly trivial if the Hilbert transform, i.e. the conjugate-function operator, were bounded on $C(\Bbb T)$. But the Hilbert transform is not bounded on $C(\Bbb T)$; the one result nonetheless follows from the other by a little trick.

For $n=1,2\dots$ define $$s_n:C(\Bbb T)\to C(\Bbb T)$$by saying $s_n f$ is the $n$-th partial sum of the Fourier series for $f$. Let $||s_n||$ denote the norm of $s_n$ as a operator on $C(\Bbb T)$. Note that $s_n:A\to A$; let $||s_n||_H$ be the norm of the restriction of $s_n$ to $A$. It is enough to show that $$||s_n||_H\to\infty;$$then the Uniform Boundedness Principle shows that there exists $f\in A$ with $||s_nf||$ unbounded.

Recall that the standard [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860448/a-continuous-function-with-a-divergent-fourier-series/1860478#1860478) of the existence of a continuous function with a divergent Fourier series proceeds by showing that $$||s_n||\to\infty;$$hence it's enough to show that $$||s_n||\le2\sup_k||s_k||_H:=2c.$$

Suppose that $p(t)=\sum_{n=-N}^Na_ne^{int}$is a trigonometric polynomial, and let $$q(t)=e^{iNt}p(t),$$so that $q\in A$ (or rather, so that there exists $f\in A$ with $q(t)=f(e^{it})$). If $n\ge N$ then $s_np=p$. On the other hand, if $n<N$ then $$s_np(t)=e^{-iNt}(s_{N+n}q-s_{N-n}q),$$so that $$||s_np||\le2c||q||= 2c||p||.$$Since the trigonometric polynomials are dense in the continuous functions (and certainly $c\ge1$) this shows that $$||s_n||\le 2c.$$

Comment: Oh ok. Let $\tilde{s_n} \in A^*,  \tilde{s}_n(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$ be the analytic version of $s_n \in C(\mathbb{T})^*$. You show that if  $\tilde{s}_n$ is uniformly bounded (on the analytic functions), then $s_n$ is uniformly bounded on the trigonometric polynomials, which means by density that $s_n$ is uniformly bounded on the continuous functions, a contradiction.

Comment: (and it is useful to note that $s_n[e^{i N t} g(t)] = s_n [g(t)]$)

Comment: Not quite - $s_nf$ is not what you said, it's $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{((k)}(0)}{k!}z^k$. Regarding your second comment, I don't know where you got that from, but useful to note or not, it's not so.

Comment: $s_n  f$ is the $n$-truncated Fourier series evaluated at $0$, otherwise all you'll show is that there is a $f$ such that $s_n f$ isn't bounded as $n \to \infty$, i.e. its Fourier series doesn't converge uniformly (but it can converge pointwise)

Comment: In the $C(\mathbb{T})$ world : with $D_N(t) = \frac{\sin((N+1/2)t)}{\sin(t/2)}$ and $\Lambda_N g = \sum_{n=-N}^N \langle g,e^{int} \rangle = \int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t) D_N(t) dt$. For showing $\|\Lambda_N\| \ge \|D_N\|_{L^1}$, it is enough to choose
$h_N(t) = \text{sign}(D_N(.)) \ast \varphi_\epsilon(t)$ (where $\varphi_\epsilon$ is a set of mollifier making $h_N(t)$ continuous). Clearly $\|h_N\| = 1$, and $\Lambda_N h_N = \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)+ \|D_N\|_{L^1}$, i.e. $\|\Lambda_N\| \ge \|D_N\|_{L^1}$.

Comment: Now in the analytic world, can you find such an explicit set of functions $\tilde{h}_N(z)$ showing $ \|\Lambda_N\|_{A^*} \to \infty$ ?

Comment: Fine - that's not what I had in mind, but I should have, gives a stronger result. Was early morning... Btw we shouldn't call that $s_n$, because $s_n f$ is a fairly standard notation for the partial sum itself. Can I find an explicit $\tilde h_N$? That was where I started - didn't see exactly how, realized I didn't have to... (This is the point to my comment about the Hilbert transform; if it were bounded on $C(\Bbb T)$ then you could just let $\tilde h_N$ be the holomorphic part of $h_N$.)

Comment: tks a lot anyway.

Comment: it seems [David Speyer gave an explicit example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287854/276986)

Comment: with say $M_k = \lfloor e^{k^3} \rfloor, N_k = 3\sum_{l \le k} M_l$