# Fourier Series on $L^1\left(\left[0,1\right)\right)\cap C\left(\left[0,1\right)\right)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, pointwise-convergence

My professor claimed that

> if $f\in L^1\left(\left[0,1\right)\right)\cap C\left(\left[0,1\right)\right)$, then
>   $$f\left(t\right)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c\left(k\right)\exp\left(2\pi ikt\right).$$

I think that this is false.

Should it be that $f\in L^2\left(\left[0,1\right)\right)$ instead?

Comment: One note: if $c(k)$ is the $k$th fourier coefficient of $f$, then it should be $f(t) = \sum_k c(k)exp(2\pi ikt)$ (i.e. no minus sign in the exponential).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By $[0,1)$, they mean the Torus, which is compact. So $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ implies it's in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ and, in particular, in $L^1$ and $L^2$.

Comment: In other words, we only need that $f\in C\left(\left[0,1\right)\right)$, right?

Comment: By the way, is it standard to denote $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ by $\left[0,1\right)$?

Comment: Yes; Yes, I think

Comment: To complement mathworker21's answer. For the Fourier series to be defined it is enough that $f\in L^1$. Convergence of the series to the original function requieres further conditions on $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if he means convergence for every $x$ then this is false. Of course it's true for convergence *in* the $L62$ norm, and (although this is a *very* difficult theorem) it's true for almost everywhere convergence.

It's well known that there exists a continuous (hence integrable) function on the circle with a Fourier series that diverges at at least one point. This is trivial from the [Uniform Boundedness Principle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860448/a-continuous-function-with-a-divergent-fourier-series)